# Using loc on concated dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Good day.
I am trying to do a relatively simple thing but can't get what is wrong.
I have two dataframes: df and df2
Each dataframe has column 'Account' containg 5 symbol code for a client and a 'Client Name' with its full name. I want to loop through unique values of 'Account' and get corresponding 'Client Name' value.
Code below worked perfectly:

```
for x in df['Account'].unique():

    worksheet.write(row, 4, df.loc[df[df['Account'] == x].index[0], 'Client Name'])
```

However later I had to merge 2 dataframes so i used concat

```
modified_df = pd.concat([pd.concat([df['Account'], df2['Account']]),
                 pd.concat([df['Client Name'], df2['Client Name']])], axis=1)
```

And surprisingly, when i substituted df for modified_df it stopped working.
Pycharm highlights 'loc' with advice: 'Unresolved attribute reference ‘loc’ for class ‘type'

And when i run code a following error occures: 'TypeError: cannot convert the series to class 'float''

I checked, both df and modified_df are pandas dataframe class

Below are sample dataframes

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['A', 'Company A'], ['B', 'Company B'], ['A', 'Company A']]),columns=['Account', 'Client Name'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['C', 'Company C'], ['B', 'Company B'], ['A', 'Company A']]),columns=['Account', 'Client Name'])
modified_df = pd.concat([pd.concat([df['Account'], df2['Account']]),
                     pd.concat([df['Client Name'], df2['Client Name']])], axis=1)
```

What I expect to get is a list "Company A, Company B, Company C"

***Update***
Playing around with above sample data I noticed that concated df's indicies are somewhat not unique. I have two sets of (0, 1, 2) indicies... Guessing it is the root of my problem.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please add sample data to your question to create a reproducible problem. This will enable users to test your code and answer more effectively. You may create sample dataframes using pandas library

Comment: Hi! Thank you for welcoming! As per your advice I added sample data. Hope it helps..

Comment: I tried with eh sample data, and `modified_df.loc[modified_df[modified_df['Account'] == x].index[0], 'Client Name']` is working fine.

Comment: Yeah, for some reason it works on this sample data. But it works incorrectly, due to not unique indicies. (i updated my problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is the duplicated index, why don't you get the first row where the `Account == x`:

```
for x in df['Account'].unique():
    worksheet.write(row, 4, df.loc[df.Account == x, 'Client Name'].iloc[0])
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked too! At time of posting the question I didn't know that the problem was in duplicated indicies)

Answer (score 1):

Found that the reason was duplicated indicies, so i just reset them and everything worked

```
modified_df = pd.concat([pd.concat([df['Client Name'], df2['Client Name']]),
                     pd.concat([df['Account'], df2['Account']])], axis=1)
modified_df = pd.concat([modified_df], ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you may have a value in your df2[Account] that can't be converted to float.

Comment: But they are the same.. And when i used loop seperately on each df everything worked..

Comment: Try with head(5) in both dataframes (10 rows in modified_df ), explore modified_df and df.dtypes in the 3 df to see types.